# Subdomain returns forbidden, 403 errors - has to do with .htaccess

Tags: apache-httpd, htaccess

I work on a domain and any number of subdomains, which are hosted externally. Inside the directory for the subdomain, there is a .htaccess file, as there are in every subdomain directory. When visiting the subdomain, I was greeted with:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Our host checked error logs, and concluded that it was due to a permissions/formatting issue. By the end, they had changed the name of the file, which was changed back, and the site seemed to work for a time. Currently, the site is in limbo of 'working' and throwing the above error message, and switches between states every few minutes.

There seems to be a temporary fix when the file's name is changed. My only lead is that the subdomain, `eod`, may be the cause. We have never experienced any such issues, nor any with .htaccess files. What may be the cause, and what are possible fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was eventually troubleshooted by the sysadmins over at our host. There were conflicting configuration files. Problem solved. *victory dance*